# jQuery UI Autocomplete: Determine if search window is open?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I want to trigger a search in the onclick event of my input, but only if the search window isn't already open. Presently, I do this:

```
$(this).bind('click.ajaxselect', function(e) {
    if(!$(this).autocomplete('widget').is(':visible')) {
        $(this).autocomplete('search','');
    }
});
```

But I'm not overly fond of using the `:visible` selector because it searches up through all the parents as well. Is there some property I can check?

[Dialog has this `isOpen` method](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#method-isOpen), does autocomplete have something similar?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Wouldn't be hard to set a simple variable:

```
$('.my_selector').bind('autocompleteopen', function(event, ui) {
    $(this).data('is_open',true);
});

$('.my_selector').bind('autocompleteclose', function(event, ui) {
    $(this).data('is_open',false);
});
```

Then your listener is easy:

```
$(this).bind('click.ajaxselect', function(e) {
    if(!$(this).data('is_open')) {
        $(this).autocomplete('search','');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty late to the party, but I have an alternative, more performant solution to this. Since all that needs to be done is **check the value of a CSS attribute**, using a state variable and two event handlers to update said variable seems like a very heavy (and possibly brittle) solution. I feel that this style of coding is what makes parts of the javascript-driven web feel sluggish, even though we're provided with enormous computing power nowadays. But I digress.

You can test for the CSS `display` attribute like this:

```
$(this).bind('click.ajaxselect', function(e) {
    if($(this).autocomplete('widget')[0].style.display === 'none') {
        $(this).autocomplete('search','');
    }
});
```

For completeness, here's how to implement such a check in a "context-free" function:

```
function isSearchWindowOpen(id_of_input_element_the_autocomplete_is_bound_to) {
    return $('#' + id_of_input_element_the_autocomplete_is_bound_to)
        .data('ui-autocomplete')          /* jquery's internal wrapper object */
        .widget()[0]                      /* the actual search window DOM element */
        .style.display === 'block';       /* standard display CSS attribute */
}
```

Comment: I don't think this is more elegant. You're relying on an implementation detail. There are other ways to show and hide things. Also, you have a potential escaping problem if `id_of_input_element_the_autocomplete_is_bound_to` contains any funny characters such as `[` or `.`.

Comment: @mpen: Do you think `.style.display` is an implementation detail (suggesting it might change in the future?). In 2016? OK, maybe "elegant" is a subjective term, but it will definitely perform better. I'll edit that.

Comment: @mpen: Anyway thanks for your input. I needed this exact functionality in a project just now, and I needed it in just a few places, so I know my inputs quite well. For the general case, you're right, weird characters without added escaping might screw something up.

Comment: Yes. There are other ways to make something invisible. Off the top of my head: you can set opacity to 0, place it off the edge of the screen, or detach it from the DOM. It's also conceivable that W3C will add a proper show/hide feature in JS so that you don't have 'remember' the previous `display` property.

Comment: @mpen: Sure, there are (and of course, there will be even) more other ways, but this is (and I'm pretty sure it will remain) the basic form of toggling something in JS.